# What is the most efficient way to copy some properties from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say, I have an object:

```
const user = {_id: 1234, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}
```

I want to create another object without the `_id` key:

```
const newUser = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}
```

I am using this:

```
const newUser = Object.assign({}, {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName})
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can achieve it with a form of *destructuring*:

```js
const user = { _id: 1234, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' };
const { _id, ...newUser } = user;
console.debug(newUser);
```

*Browser support:*

The spread (`...`) syntax was introduced with ES2018, and most browsers even supported it before ES2018 was finalized. So as of 2023, you can rely on browser support unless you need to support very old browsers.
Alternatively, you may use it with a "transpilation" layer such as Babel.

Comment: currently stage 4, according to the first link

Comment: Please note that this will also create an `_id` variable.

Comment: @RedGuy11 that's not true, the destructure pulls the `_id` value out of `user` and assigns it to a new variable `_id` while adding the rest of the properties to a new `newUser` object. The downside with this approach is that if the `user` object is modified over time, you may have to modify the destructuring statement to define what properties are omitted. Basically there is a decision of whether you would rather pull the specific name values or remove the id value if the user object changes over time.

Comment: I was pointing out that the `_id` variable would be created

Answer (score 7):

Do it with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

```js
const user = {
  _id: 1234,
  fistName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};

var res = Object.keys(user).reduce(function(obj, k) {
  if (k != '_id') obj[k] = user[k];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I wonder how this can be faster than the assignment that the OP makes.

Comment: @trincot - why not read the question, it says *"I want to create another object without the `_id` key"*, and then the OP shows the object that is the expected result, and goes on to say that he's using `Object.assign`, which is not direct assigment.

Comment: Indeed, the `Object.assign` is of course superfluous in the OP's code.

Comment: @trincot :  `Object.assign({}, {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName})` is same as simple assigning `{firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName}`.. I think he want to copy all other property except `_id`.... in case he don't knows what are the property which have?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I understand that it is nice to have a generic solution, but the OP is not clear on that, as he seems to have a working solution that has hard-coded property names. For your first statement: I agree the outcome is the same, but with `Object.assign` two new objects are created (cf. the two object literals) instead of one, and so also the shallow copy is taken twice, not once.

Comment: @trincot `const newUser = {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName}` is enough .... what he is expecting as result is not at all clear.... I think he need a generic solution for doing that...

Comment: I agree that is enough (it is what [I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40564052/5459839)), and I agree his expectations are not clear. We can only wait for the OP's return from his absence :)

Answer (score 5):

You are taking a shallow copy twice: once with the object literal, and again with `Object.assign`. So just use the first of the two:

```
const newUser = {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName};
```

Answer (score 3):

Go through the object keys, put the **wanted property keys** in an array and use the `Array.prototype.includes()` to copy only these into the new object.

```js
const account = {
  id: 123456,
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  login: "john123",
  site_admin: false,
  blog: "https://opensource.dancingbear/",
  email: "john123@example.com",
  bio: "John ❤️ Open Source",
  created_at: "2001-01-01T01:30:18Z",
  updated_at: "2020-02-16T21:09:14Z"
};

function selectSomeProperties(account) {
return Object.keys(account).reduce(function(obj, k) {
    if (["id", "email", "created_at"].includes(k)) {
        obj[k] = account[k];
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
const selectedProperties = selectSomeProperties(account);
console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedProperties))
```

The result:

```
{"id":123456,"email":"john123@example.com","created_at":"2001-01-01T01:30:18Z"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient would most likely be a regular loop

```js
const user = {_id: 1234, fistName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'};
let   obj  = {}, key;

for (key in user) {
  if ( key !== '_id' ) obj[key] = user[key];
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: How can a loop be faster than the direct assignment that the OP performs?

Comment: @trincot - `Object.assign` is not "direct assigment", it's an internal method that iterates, does some checks, and creates a new object, and it's not very efficient -> **https://jsperf.com/object-copy-efficiency-s**. Of course, if the op **can** use direct assigment, and can reference the keys directly, that's faster, but this just leaves out the `_id` property, like the other answers, and assumes one doesn't always want to use all the keys.

Comment: Indeed, the `Object.assign` is of course superfluous in the OP's code.

Comment: @trincot - of course, as the properties are primitives, the `assign` call isn't needed at all, the OP is passing the object he wants to `Object.assign` and gets a copy of the exact same object, I just assumed the point was to leave out the `_id` property when creating the new object, not reference the other properties directly ?

Comment: The question is indeed ambiguous. The OP writes *I am currently using this*, which would not be a possibility if the solution had to work for objects with other properties in his code as well. Not sure now.

Answer (score 1):

This tiny function will select specific keys to either copy or exclude from copying. exclude take precedence:

```js
function copy(obj, include=[], exclude=[]) {

  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((target, k) => {

    if (exclude.length) {
      if (exclude.indexOf(k) < 0) target[k] = obj[k];
    } else if (include.indexOf(k) > -1) target[k] = obj[k];
    return target;
  }, {});
}

// let's test it
const user = {
  _id: 1234,
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};

// both will return the same result but have different uses.
console.log(
  'include only firstName and lastName:\n', 
  copy(user, ['firstName', 'lastName'])
);
console.log(
  'exclude _id:\n',
  copy(user, null, ['_id'])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 'better way' you're just looking for a more elegant-looking way, the way I usually do it is:

```
const { firstName, lastName } = user;
const newUser = { firstName, lastName };
```

it's probably not so efficient, and it also "contaminates" the scope with two more variables, but it's short and at least you're specifying the variables you need instead of the ones you want to exclude.