# JavaScript object literals and ES6 - syntatic sugar to deconstruct large object into smaller ones?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-literal

What I'm wondering is; is there a simpler syntatic shortcut to what I'm trying to do here.

I have one large JSON object during a loop, like so:

```
let line = {
    first_name: ...,
    last_name: ...,
    title: ...,
    email: ...,
    facebook_account: ...,
    linkedin_account: ...,
    twitter_account: ...,
    instagram_account: ...,
    snapchat_account: ...
};
```

I then break this payload down into smaller objects:

```
let profile = {
    first_name: line.first_name,
    last_name: line.last_name,
    title: line.title,
    email: line.email
};

let social = {
    facebook_account: line.facebook_account,
    linkedin_account: line.linkedin_account,
    twitter_account: line.twitter_account,
    instagram_account: line.instagram_account,
    snapchat_account: line.snapchat_account 
};
```

Does ES6 afford me a way to cut the repetition of each property i.e. first_name, facebook_account, etc.? The property names are not necessarily obvious in regards to how they get broken down - it's based on our data model.

This is a lot of manual work w/ a lot of repetition. I wonder if I'm missing some piece of ES6 magic, or something, that'd pretty this up. I'm not really looking for a super clever recursive loop with a machine learning algorithm...just shorter syntax, if possible. :)

Comment: More accurately [this answer with a `pluck()` prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240713/247893).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use object destructoring:

`let {variables} = obj`

and individual variable assignment:

`let obj2 = { variables }`

Variables can be multiple and separated by commas.

When destructoring: `let {name, date, whatever} = obj;`

and when assigning: `let obj2 = { name, date, whatever }`

```js
let line = {
    first_name: "Zak",
    last_name: "Frisch",
    title: "my Title",
    email: "myemail@whatever",
    facebook_account: "fb",
    linkedin_account: "li",
    twitter_account: "tweet",
    instagram_account: "ia",
    snapchat_account: "sc"
};

let {first_name, last_name, title, email, facebook_account, linkedin_account, twitter_account, instagram_account, snapchat_account} = line;

let profile = {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    title,
    email
};

let social = {
    facebook_account,
    linkedin_account,
    twitter_account,
    instagram_account,
    snapchat_account
};
console.log(profile, social);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40562673/1582065) answer, you can do this:

```js
let line = {
    first_name: "Zak",
    last_name: "Frisch",
    title: "my Title",
    email: "myemail@whatever",
    facebook_account: "fb",
    linkedin_account: "li",
    twitter_account: "tweet",
    instagram_account: "ia",
    snapchat_account: "sc"
};

let profile = Object.keys(line).reduce(function(obj, k) {
  if (!k.endsWith('_account')) obj[k] = line[k];
  return obj;
}, {});

let social = Object.keys(line).reduce(function(obj, k) {
  if (k.endsWith('_account')) obj[k] = line[k];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(line);

console.log(profile);

console.log(social);
```