# How to copy some properties from an object to another

Tags: typescript

I have an object `listData` with the following values:

```
{
    "TestId": 2,
    "CurrentTestVersion": 1,
    "TestNumber": "2015-29059",
    "SharingData": 1.000000,
    "ThresholdValue": 0.0,
    "ExpireDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
    "UpdateDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00",
    "TestCurrency": "INR",
    "TestCode": "44300",
    "TestUCode": "",
    "IndexType": "LME",
    "IndexCode": "EUR",

}
```

I need to create one more object with only selected fields like:

```
{
    "TestId": 2,
    "CurrentTestVersion": 1,
    "ThresholdValue": 0.0,
    "ExpireDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
    "TestCurrency": "INR",
    "TestCode": "44300",
    "TestUCode": "",
}
```

I have checked with [What is the most efficient way to copy some properties from an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562647/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-copy-some-properties-from-an-object-in-javascr), which works well with JavaScript but not with TypeScript; any better ways to selectively copy properties?

Comment: What _specific problem_ have you had adapting those JS answers to your use case? The runtime behaviour is the same so it should just be a case of adding type information, no? Give a [mre].

Comment: Could you use `Pick<typeof the_object, ...your_keys>`? Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a mapper something like this:

```
  const objMapper = (obj: { [key: string]: string | number }, keys: string[]) => {
    const result: { [key: string]: string | number } = {};

    for (const k of keys) {
      if (obj[k]) {
        result[k] = obj[k];
      }
    }

    return result;
  };
```

and you can call it like this:

```
const result = objMapper({
    "TestId": 2,
    "CurrentTestVersion": 1,
    "TestNumber": "2015-29059",
    "SharingData": 1.000000,
    "ThresholdValue": 0.0,
    "ExpireDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
    "UpdateDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00",
    "TestCurrency": "INR",
    "TestCode": "44300",
    "TestUCode": "",
    "IndexType": "LME",
    "IndexCode": "EUR",

}, ["TestId", "CurrentTestVersion", ...]);
```

and it will return your custom object

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works well with static JSON, but when I try with dynamic JSON object , the result is null.
var PistData = this.TestDetails.userDetails;
          const result = this.objMapper({
            PistData
          }, ["TestId"])
          console.log("result pist:", result);

Comment: Can you tell me what will be the result if you change ```result = this.objMapper({ PistData })```  to ```result = this.objMapper({ ...PistData }, ['TestId']);``` ?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to remove the extra property, since you are working with type script, you must have two interface/class to represent respective the structures.
eg:

```
        AllProperty ap; // source
        SomeProperty sp; // target
        
  // Sine in your example your object does not have any reference type property , 
 // you can simply transfer the values to a new object.
        
        var sp = Object.assign(sp, ap) as SomeProperty;
```

If you want to remove properties for some other reason (data being sent through API)

```
you can either use 'delete' keyword, ... spread operator etc
```